# Problem with inserting vector elements into map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

While putting sorted vector elements into map, it inserts them in ascending order after it has been sorted in descending order with the compare function. I know that map is in ascending order by default based on its key, but I am not sure why it sorts them again in ascending order based on its value. Is this common in std::map<std::string, int>?

I simply want to return a map in descending order by its value, I need to display the directory strings with a number of items found by decreasing order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool compare_dir(std::pair<std::string, int>&a,
                 std::pair<std::string, int>&b)
{
    return a.second > b.second; 
}

void sort_func(std::map<std::string, int>& M)
{
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator itr; 
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> temp;
    std::map<std::string, int> result; 

    for(auto &it : M)
        temp.push_back(it); 


    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), compare_dir); 

     
    for(auto &el : temp)
        std::cout << el.first << " " << el.second << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl; 


    for(auto & el : temp)
        result.insert(el);  


    for(itr = result.begin(); itr != result.end(); itr++)
        std::cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second << std::endl; 
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> my_map{{"dir1", 1}, {"dir2", 2}, {"dir3", 3}}; 
    
    for (const auto& [key, value] : my_map) {
        std::cout << '[' << key << "] = " << value << "; " << std::endl; 

    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 

    sort_func(my_map); 
}
```

Comment: "but I am not sure why it sorts them again in ascending order based on its value." unclear what you mean by that.  Please include expected and actual output in the question

Comment: you sort the vector and then insert the same elements into the map that were present in the map before. Why would this result in a different order?

Comment: There is no way to sort `std::map` based on value. It's always sorted on key (with sorting method of your choice, ascending by default).

Comment: note that in your example sorting with respect to keys results in the same order as sorting with respect to mapped values. You may use an example where the order actually differs

Comment: use a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>>` rather than the map, then you can sort it as you like

Comment: okay, I see my problem now, but I created an empty map result, how can the map have the values present when it's empty already?

Comment: you insert the elements in this line `result.insert(el);`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I cannot simply use std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>, I have hundreds of files with thousands of matches for a string, I need to hold the values by key, but I may return a vector of pairs. Would be really cumbersome to change the whole code I am writing.

Comment: if you want a `std::map` to be sorted by mapped values there is no way around chaning your code, because it isnt possible

Comment: anyhow I still don't understand what you actually want to do, or what output you did expect. Please include output and expected output in the question

Comment: I can just return a vector of pairs with directory names and their values as you hinted out with std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>  sorted with the values based on the key, it works in my case and I may return this vector and insert this logic to manipulate my log and txt files. but if I start trying to find the directories with matched keys without mapping, that would be a huge problem. I solved the problem. It's just not possible to return a map in the format I was expecting.